# OpenGL and gluLookAt function

Tags: opengl, glut

I have function moveCamera() that rotate camera around center sphere.

```
void moveCamera()
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    int vec = ceil(theta / 3.1415);
    int y;
    if (vec%2)
        y = 1;
    else
        y = -1;
    gluLookAt(e_x, e_y, e_z, 0, 0, 0, 0, y, 0);
}
```

This function is called inside display()

```
void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    moveCamera();

    glCallList(idList);

    GLfloat pos[] = {0, 0, 0, 1};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);

    glFinish();
}
```

In this situation all works fine. But I noticed some things, that I cannot explain.

For example, if I modify display() function for drawing red line in the direction X-axis like this

```
void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glLineWidth(5);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(0, 0, 0);
        glVertex3i(1000, 0, 0);
    glEnd();

    moveCamera();

    glCallList(idList);

    GLfloat pos[] = {0, 0, 0, 1};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);

    glFinish();
}
```

... nothing happened. Why???

Another, if I remove glLoadIdentity() after glClear() the red line will draw, but when I move the camera by keyboard buttons, I see some bug in rendering this line (the line change their coordinates for drawing). For see it, run my code.

The full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <QDebug>
using namespace std;

#define WIDTH 1024
#define HEIGHT 600

void display();
void reshape(int width, int height);
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void moveCamera();
void init();
void mkList();
void enableLight();
//double z(const double &x, const double &y);
void printMatrix(double *m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        qDebug() << QString("%1   %2   %3   %4").arg(m[i*4]).arg(m[i*4+1]).arg(m[i*4+2]).arg(m[i*4+3]);
    qDebug() << "\n";
}

GLuint idList = 0;

double e_x = 0;
double e_y = 0;
double e_z = 0;
double r = 300;
double phi = 0;
double theta = 1.5;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(30, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Lab#2");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    init();
    mkList();
    enableLight();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glLineWidth(5);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(0, 0, 0);
        glVertex3i(1000, 0, 0);
    glEnd();

    moveCamera();

    glCallList(idList);

    GLfloat pos[] = {0, 0, 0, 1};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos);

    glFinish();
}

void reshape(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(45, 2, 100, 2000);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
#define ESCAPE '\033'

    switch (key)
    {
    case ESCAPE:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case 's':
        theta += 0.1;
        break;
    case 'w':
        theta -= 0.1;
        break;
    case 'a':
        phi += 0.1;
        break;
    case 'd':
        phi -= 0.1;
        break;
    case 'q':
        r-=5;
        break;
    case 'e':
        r+=5;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    e_x = r * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
    e_z = r * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
    e_y = r * cos(theta);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void moveCamera()
{
    glLoadIdentity();
    int vec = ceil(theta / 3.1415);
    int y;
    if (vec%2)
        y = 1;
    else
        y = -1;
    gluLookAt(e_x, e_y, e_z, 0, 0, 0, 0, y, 0);
}

void init()
{
    e_x = r * sin(theta) * cos(phi);
    e_z = r * sin(theta) * sin(phi);
    e_y = r * cos(theta);
}

void mkList()
{
    int idInnerList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(idInnerList, GL_COMPILE);

    glColor3ub(255, 0, 0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(-200, 0, 0);
    glutWireSphere(50, 10, 10);
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3ub(0, 255, 0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(200, 0, 0);
    glutSolidCube(100);
    glPopMatrix();

    glEndList();

    idList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(idList, GL_COMPILE);
    glCallList(idInnerList);

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, 200);
    glCallList(idInnerList);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -200);
    glCallList(idInnerList);
    glPopMatrix();
    glEndList();
}

void enableLight()
{
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE);

    GLfloat diffuse[] = {0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1};

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
}
```

Comment: So, I noticed, that function moveCamera(), and that gluLookAt() must be called firtly in display function(). Why???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, I want to say this: it's 2016 - don't use legacy OpenGL. Read up on modern OpenGL with the help of your favorite search engine.

If by "nothing happened" you mean "i couldn't see the red line" and if I understood your code correctly, that's just because the line will be entirely clipped. Let me explain.

The first thing you do that affects vertex transformation inside `display()` is call `glLoadIdentity()`. This will set the top of the current matrix stack to the identity matrix, `I`. Let's assume the current stack is `MODELVIEW` and the current projection matrix, `P`, is the one set in `reshape()`, then your line will undergo the following transformation from local-space into clip-space:

```
Vx_clip = P * I * Vx_local
Vy_clip = P * I * Vy_local
```

Given that the model-view matrix is the identity, both local coordinates will remain the same in world-space before being transformed into clip-space. Since your near plane is at `z=-100`, the line will be completely out of the frustum, i.e. not in the space between the near- and the far-plane, and thus be clipped entirely. Mathematically this is a little more involved, but it's conceptually accurate.

You can convince yourself by defining the red line like this

```
glVertex3i(-500, 0, -100);
glVertex3i(500, 0, -100);
```

Now, part of the line will be inside inside your frustum, even with an identity model-view matrix, because it partially intersects the near plane and thus must not be entirely clipped.

If you apply a non-identity model-view matrix first by calling `moveCamera()` **before** rendering the red-line, you'll also be able to partially see the red line. Why? Well, let's assume your polar coordinates are chosen so that the camera will still look in the direction `(0, 0, -z)`, then with the given radius, you define the camera to be at (0, 0, 300) in world-space, which `gluLookAt()` will map to a transformation matrix which will simply add a translation of (0, 0, -300) to both vertices.

Given the initial definition of your line and the new model-view matrix the vertices of the line will be at `(0, 0, -300)` and `(1000, 0, -300)` after left-multiplying the model-view matrix. After transformation to clip-space by left-multiplying the projection matrix, the line will be only partially clipped and thus be visible.

As I said, this is much more involved and in fact, this is only part of the complete vertex transformation pipeline. Read [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) and [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html) for a mathematical treatise of the subject of vertex transformation. It's computer-graphics 101. And please: focus on the math, not on the use of the legacy API that you'll unfortunately see there.